# php base_convert not working for non-integers?

Tags: php, base-conversion

I want to write `3.1415` (written under base ten) in base 8 using php. 

I'm expecting `3.11034`, but `base_convert(3.1415,10,8);` is returning `75267`...

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) says the first parameter should be a number but it clearly interprets it as an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the php doc you specified, the `base_convert` function defined like this:

```
base_convert ( string $number , int $frombase , int $tobase ) : string
```

We can see that the `$number` parameter should be a string, but if we replace the number `3.1415` in your example with string contains the same number, it still doesn't works. But you must pay attention to the parameters specification down in the page:

> **number** - The number to convert. Any invalid characters in number are
>   silently ignored.

Apparently the function ignoring some characters. The most reasonable thing we can think, is that the function maybe consider the decimal point as an invalid character, after all - the function converts the number to string as I mentioned. I ran a test, turns out the function returns `75267` when I set the number to `31415` (without the decimal point).

**Conclusion**: The function consider the decimal point as a invalid character, and the number can be an Integer only.